# How to create a 4 dynamic variable table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The title may be misleading. I don't how to begin solving this without creating an absurd amount of data, which I'd like to avoid. This may also be posted on the wrong site. If so, please educate me. Thanks!!!

I have these variables: `Employee Name`, `Job Name`, `Week Ending On`, and `Hours worked`.

`Hours` is dependent of all 3 other variables.

`Job Name`, `Employee Name`, and `Week Ending On` are independent. I think.

I have a userform in which I enter in each employee's hours worked per job that I submit each week.

This userform is what's generating all of my data. So far that just leaves me with a spreadsheet each week but I'd like to make a pivot table and a graph to show how many cumulative hours were worked on a specific job, and also see the cumulative hours an employee worked a specific job.

Those can be independent, I'll never need to see them at the same time, hence why I wanted to use a pivot table.

Unfortunately, I don't know the proper names of this type of data analysis and haven't been able to find anything that fits my needs on this site, or google.

What would be the most efficient way to organize this data on a single spreadsheet, so that I can create a pivot table or something similar to meet my needs?

Below is a picture of what I was trying, but this would end up being a nightmare trying to code.

[image]

All of the ranges are dynamic, as in from the userform I'll be able to edit the employee name and job name ranges. The week ending range will also just keep getting added to.

I don't want to do it like how it is in the picture, is there a better way that I'm ignorant to?

Comment: Try using excel tables to organize your data. In addition to the 4 you have listed Employee_Name, Job_Name, Week_Ending_On, Hours_Worked, you may want to add Comments, & Valid, Valid when set to false should not be included in total hours, etc.  This is the first steps toward using a database.  (Data processing and data structures are the two subject names generally associated with this class of problems. )

Comment: @bvaughn Thank you for your comment. I'll give excel tables a whirl and see what I can come up with. I've thus far accomplished all my goals using vba, so admittedly my actual excel skills are pretty dismal.

Comment: @jcbermu Thank you for editing my post into a more readable format!!!

Comment: In your example, the left creates the right side, but the numbers are entered manually?

Comment: @Raystafarian  Yes, the userform has a combo box that's populated by the A column to select employee, another combo box populated by B for job names, and the C column is automatically made every time the program opens (deletes repeats too). The hours are the only thing manually entered and dependent on everything. I am working on finding a way to better sort this data, because employee's and job's will be added and deleted as time goes on, causing me to probably have to make a worksheet for every single employee, which I'd like to avoid. I'm open to any and all advice!

Comment: I think maybe you're going about this backward - basically it's a overall view of time cards, yes? The time card (form) can be weekly or biweekly for the employees where they can only select the job and enter hours. Then those all feed into your data which is the basis of your end-resulting table. Basically limit the scope of the manual entry and feed it into a database.

Comment: @Raystafarian I added 2 more pictures to show the userform and the time sheet. The time sheet gets saved and exported as a pdf from the 'save as' button. But yes, basically I want an overall view of the data from all entered time cards. I wanted to be able to sort it either by job, or by employee. I think what I'll end up having to do is generate a worksheet for each individual employee... I was hoping there would be a more compact way of storing the data though.

Comment: Pivot table. Once you have the data, pivot table.

Comment: Thank you @Raystafarian for your help and guidance through this. With some proper google searches based on what you guys talked about, I was able to see how simple this really was. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of editing your question please post your solution as an answer. That's the proper form on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved! Thank you everyone who helped guide me.**

Once I got into it and realized what I had in mind was impossible, this result became obvious. Wasn't difficult to code, and it is easy to modify.

Picture showing the final product for the data structure:
[image: final product for the data structure.]

Comment: How did you accomplish this? In order for your solution to be helpful in the future, it must contain good details.